# Would the Two Witnesses be a governor and a priest?

Tags: revelation, david, zechariah

Usually, I favor more allegorical interpretation, especially of Genesis and Revelation, but I am dedicated to a literal gloss on at least the existence of two specific persons who are the referents of the prophecy, here.

I'm generally aware of the Enoch/Elijah thesis, the Moses/Elijah thesis can be defended in light of the Transfiguration episode, and I used to think the Peter/Paul thesis was strong. But I found out about the correspondence of Revelation, here, with Zechariah, so could the TW either be Joshua and Zerubabbel themselves, returned in spirit like Elijah from John the Baptist at least, or at least a political figure and a church figure, correlated like Joshua and Zerubabbel?

(Also, how might this allow for a typology of the TW in Jonathan and David?)

Comment: Ok until I have time to edit my question, I flagged my own post  my apologies, when the autoreview of the post went through, I thought there was nothing to add.

Answer (score 2):

I am somewhat mystified by the question as it appears to beg a certain type of answer rather than allowing the Bible to speak for itself.  The only way to know anything about the two witnesses is to identify them by their precedents and allusions in the rest of the Bible.

Here is the lost of characteristics used to describe the two witnesses, in Rev 11:

- V3: prophesy for 1260 days (compare Rev 12:6, and 42 months of Rev 11:2, 13:4, and 3½ years of Dan 7:25, 12:7, Rev 12:14) see also Luke 4:25, James 5:17 [Elijah]
- V3: clothed in sackcloth [and idiom for meekness and poverty] - see 2 Kings 1:7, 8 [Elijah]
- V4: two olive trees and two lampstands that stand before the Lord of the earth - compare Zech 4:2, 3, 11-14
- V5: they have the ability to kill enemies with fire - compare 2 Kings 1:9-12 [Elijah]
- V6: power to stop rain - compare 1 Kings 17:1, 18:1 [Elijah]
- V6: turn water into blood and strike the earth with plagues - compare Ex 7:17-19 [Moses]
- V10: they are also called "two prophets".

Thus, there are numerous obvious allusions to Moses and Elijah consistent with other prophecies about similar matter such as Mal 4:4, 5, Matt 17:3, 4, Mark 9:4, 5, Luke 9:30, etc.  I cannot see any allusions to Enoch, Peter, Paul, Joshua, Zerubabbel, David and Jonathon.

How one interprets this prophecy is another matter but the description cannot be ignored.

Comment: +1. Questions like this are a matter of spiritual interpretation, taking in, as you rightly say, precedents, descriptions and allusions. Many of the broad range of interpretations can be eliminated because of inconsistency or inaccurate groundwork, and one hopes to be always able to narrow everything down to one, single, logical and spiritual meaning. I agree wholeheartedly that scripture should 'speak for itself'.

Comment: I only recently heard of a link between Rev 11 and Zech 4. If you have a 2 minutes, listen to [this sermon](http://vc.org.au/podcast/the-two-witnesses/) starting at 13:00. It's not an indisputable argument, but it makes so much sense to me: Rev 11:4 is a direct reference to Zech 4 - these two witnesses/lampstands call back to Joshua and Zerubbabel, who in turn stand for two of the offices of God's people, the priest and king. But Rev 1:6 says the church is God's Kingdom of Priests, suggesting the two witnesses in chapter 11 are just another picture for the church (one of so many in this book!)